# how to conditionally add row of data when it doesn't match a list

Tags: r, missing-data, data-wrangling

I have a dataset that includes a list of ID numbers and the values associated with that ID. But this dataset is missing a row of data associated with "id4". I confirm this by checking against a list of id numbers which shows me there is a mismatch in row 4 (although in principle, it could have been any or many of the ids missing)

```r
id <- c("id1", "id2", "id3", "id5","id6");
time <- c(1, 2.5, 1, 4.5, 2);
total <- c(5,5,5,5,5);

data <- data.frame(id, time, total);data;
#>    id time total
#> 1 id1  1.0     5
#> 2 id2  2.5     5
#> 3 id3  1.0     5
#> 4 id5  4.5     5
#> 5 id6  2.0     5


id_list <- c("id1", "id2", "id3", "id4", "id5","id6");
which(id_list %in% data$id)
#> [1] 1 2 3 5 6
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

I want to add a row where missing id belongs and fill it with the correct id number (so it matches the list in "id_list") and then fill "time" and "total" with 0. The final dataset would look like this:

```
#>    id time total
#> 1 id1  1.0     5
#> 2 id2  2.5     5
#> 3 id3  1.0     5
#> 4 id4  0       0
#> 5 id5  4.5     5
#> 6 id6  2.0     5
```

But I'm not sure where to go after using %in% to identify which rows are missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `complete`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>%
    complete(id = id_list, fill = list(time = 0, total = 0))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  id     time total
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 id1     1       5
2 id2     2.5     5
3 id3     1       5
4 id4     0       0
5 id5     4.5     5
6 id6     2       5
```

Comment: Thank you! It's great to see an option using Tidyverse!

Answer (score 0):

A base R option using `merge` -

```
result <- merge(data.frame(id = id_list), data, all.x = TRUE)
result[is.na(result)] <- 0
result

#   id time total
#1 id1  1.0     5
#2 id2  2.5     5
#3 id3  1.0     5
#4 id4  0.0     0
#5 id5  4.5     5
#6 id6  2.0     5
```